# Wagtail: Limit choice dynamically based on current object

Tags: django, wagtail

How can I limit the choices for the districtobject field in wagtail admin?

```
class DistrictPage(Page):

    districtobject = models.ForeignKey(DistrictTranslated, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

I know that I can use "limit_choices_to" for basic limitations with Q. But I want to use a more dynamic approach which allows me to use the "content" of the current object. (Like self.attribute ... etc)

For example:

```
def my_limit_function(self):
    1. get parent page
    2. read date from parent page and extract this information for a filter query
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that in the Page class definition. I think you are going to need to customize the page form as in [this example in the documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#customising-generated-forms). The values can be set in the form `__init__.py`. Don't forget that there won't be a parent page until your page is saved for the first time.